# How can I include a local Java program within a GWT based project?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

The local Java program uses some of the same classes as the rest of the GWT project, but it has to access the file system.

Since the GWT compiler does not accept any Java I/O classes how can I do this? Is there a way to stop GWT from compiling certain classes or is there something in the project set up which makes this possible?

I'm developing in Eclipse if that helps.

Comment: GWT Java I/O is only available on the server side. You can pass data back and forth between client and server through RPC's.

Answer (score 1):

All java files put in the server package won't be compiled by GWT to javascript.
But they will run as a servlet on the server.

So you can not write files on the client, only on the server.